# Convert Big GeoJSON into topoJSON

Tags: javascript, json, topojson

I have [a GeoJSON file](https://github.com/jgoodall/us-maps/blob/master/geojson/zcta5.json) that's about 1.4GB, and because of the filesize (?), the command line tool doesn't work. I use topojson comman tool such as:

```
topojson {{ input file }} >> {{ output file }}
```

Web tools have the same problem (the browser just hangs).

**What's the best way to convert that huge GeoJSON file?**

Comment: Please share your command and your shapfile source (url), 1.4 GB isnt so big, it should work fine.

Comment: I'm using `topojson` on the command line.  And [this is the geojson](https://github.com/jgoodall/us-maps/blob/master/geojson/zcta5.json) I'm trying to convert.

Comment: What is the exact topojson command you use?

Comment: I use `topojson {{ input file }} >> {{ output file }}`

Comment: You should use Mike Bostock's module [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson). You can install it via npm.

Comment: @Brandon: I reworded your question, remember to keep as short as possible, and to provide all the problem's initial parameters (link to data, command line you use, buggy code, etc). You are also encouraged to validate below the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Tool

Using the [Topojson command line](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) should works fine. The API is short and well written, read it quickly.

#### Your command

```
topojson input.json >> output.json # what does `>>` ?
```

The [topojson manual](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference#input-and-output) tell us to use `>`, never the `>>` which means `append to the output file`. So I wonder if this could be the bug.

#### Simple conversion

```
topojson input.json > output.json # convert from geo to topojson.
```

This command keeps all the data from the geojson input, at same quality, and will result in a +250MB topojson file. When projected via d3js on client side, `d3.topojson` will try to converted it back into geojson (1.4GB!) so d3 can use it to generate a near 1GB svg in your browser. This is both suicidal (the workflow will crash) and pointless : topojson is designed to ease your life by simplifying gis data to suit web browsers' lower capabilites and needs. HD screens are 1980*1280, gis data are far above this and need simplifications.

#### Simplify command

Use topojson command line to **simplify** your huge geojson data. A common simplification is via `-q 1e4`:

```
  topojson -q 1e4 \
      -o out.json \
      -- input.geojson
```

So the output file will have 10.000 pseudo-pixels quality aka a lot lower than your input yet far enough for client side dataviz, and be about or under 1MB.