# Large geojson to topojson

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I am trying to convert a relatively large geojson file (383 MB) to topojson to use it with D3.js. I am running the following command on a mac book pro 2016:

```
geo2topo test.json > test.topojson
```

and also the following command for simplification:

```
geo2topo test.json > test.topojson -q 10000
```

Both of them produce the same following error:

> buffer.js:503
>       throw new Error('"toString()" failed');
>       ^
>
> Error: "toString()" failed
>       at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:503:11)
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at ReadStream. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson/node_modules/topojson-server/bin/geo2topo:107:46)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>       at ReadStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

I looked at various threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037287/convert-big-geojson-into-topojson) but haven't found any solutions. Please note that the geojson itself is properly formatted and can be loaded in d3.js, but due to its size cannot be used in web applications.

Comment: I'm running into exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm also stuck in this, my geojson has 2gb and could really use some topojson magic. AFAIK, v8 can't read more than 256mb in one gulp (so neither can node, and neither can geo2topo)

Answer (score 0):

Unaware of the actual errors being thrown I do have suggestions:

Maybe you can make use of [`ndjson`](https://github.com/mbostock/ndjson-cli)? Like `ndjson-split 'd.features' < test.json > test.ndjson`. That way you could break down your file to smaller parts or get rid of unnecessary features via [`ndjson-filter`](https://github.com/mbostock/ndjson-cli#filter).

Comment: This works around the issue (256Mb limit) by splitting into smaller files, which is what I'll try next, but what happens when you need to combine them again?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem yesterday. Specifically, the v8 engine can't read strings larger than 256Mb. Since the first step of loading the geojson is to read and parse it as a json, that doesn't work.

However, a good soul ported the node implementation to python:

https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/topojson.py

Since python doesn't have that limitation, you can use this code to create the topojson, then do whatever you want with it.